# RoR nested forms with dropzone and some insight?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, dropzone.js

I'm somewhat new to RoR, I've made some nice things in it but while trying my hand at drag and drop file uploading I came across some problems, right now I'm trying dropzone js, however I fail to understand some things, specially when it comes to making a nested form with it, I've investigated about this for 2 days now and I'm still confused on how to properly set up my form, so far I have something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@event, :html => { :multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |image|
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It's pretty straightforward, the real one has a couple more attributes but they are submitting with no problems, even the image is submitting no problem, problem is that I don't know how to use dropzone inside my form, I've tried multiple approaches and all leave me with either no dropzone or an error uploading the images to the database, any advise on how to manage this?

Comment: Did you try applying `class: "dropzone"` to the form? like `<%= form_for(@event, :html => {class: "dropzone", :multipart => true}) do |f| %>`

Comment: yes, however it makes the whole form a dropzone, more than anything I'm having trouble assigning an url to the dropzone to upload the images.

Comment: Ok any with applying that to `fields_for`?

Comment: I got an error for applying it to fields_for, I don't think you can just apply it on `fields_for` unless I did something wrong.